# how to get count of another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Like below image I have two tables, now I want to get all columns from `Restaurant` table  depending on `cat` column, and number of records from `Foods` table that have that Restaurant id.

[image]

example : (to get **1,test** from `Restaurant` table and **3** from `Foods` table).

```
$sql = "select * from Restaurant,Foods where cat=6..." ;
```

updated :

```
$sql = "r.*,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM restaurant_foods WHERE restaurant_id = r.id)
    foods_count FROM restaurant r WHERE r.cats LIKE '%,$cat,%' limit $start,$end"
```

Comment: Use an explicit `join`.

Comment: You're almost there.  Think about it -- which rows from Foods do you want to match to `Restaurant.cat = 6`?  What properties does that row have that could be tested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should do the job:

```
SELECT r.*,
       (SELECT Count(*)
        FROM   Foods
        WHERE  restaurnat_id = r.id) foods_count
FROM   Restaurant r
WHERE  r.cat = 6
```